# How to import a resource from external jar in Spring?

Tags: java, spring

I'd like to autowire a resource file that is located in an external jar.
When I put this external file in `src/main/resources` and locate it with `classpath:file` everything works fine.

How can I achieve the same with reference to the external jar?

```
//@Value("org.springframework.batch.core.schema-h2.sql") //this does not work
@Value("classpath:schema-h2.sql") //src/main/resources/schema-h2.sql
private Resource sql;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK I should have just tried replacing dots with slashed, it works the following way, just for reference someone is looking into this:

```
@Value("classpath:org/springframework/batch/core/schema-h2.sql")
private Resource sql;
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this should be a System property or a value specified in a props file instead? Its constant, so I dont see why you need it autowired in this way